# Finding the intersect of two arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, fortran95, set-intersection

I'm trying to generate the intersect of two 1-D arrays in Fortran.

The intent is to use this intersection as a mask in `maxloc` so that I can pull the max few elements from one array into another (behavior analogous to repeated root removal in a max heap).

Currently I just set the value at the index found by `maxloc` to zero after I insert the value at that index into the second array but I was hoping Fortran had a clever mask-related method for this. (It would also be nice to leave the original array intact during this procedure of max-retrieval)

Comment: If you are interested in getting the intersection of 2 arrays, that are not necessarily the same size, you can get it with a single line : 
`pack( array1, (/(any(array1(i) == array2), i=1, size(array1))/))` and the indices of the intersect elements in `array1` are given by 
`pack( (/(i, i=1, size(array1))/), (/(any(array1(i) == array2), i=1, size(array1))/))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean. If you want to compare two arrays index by index, you can do that by just using `==`, like so:

```
INTEGER :: a(4), b(4)
LOGICAL :: inter(4)

a = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4 /)
b = (/ 4, 2, 3, 1 /)
inter = (a == b)  ! (/ F, T, T, F /)
```

This is not technically an intersection, but the `MASK` in `MAXLOC` needs to be an array of `LOGICAL`, so I assumed that that is what you want.

If you want to test whether a value of `a` is anywhere in `b`, you have to use at least one `DO` loop, I think:

```
DO j = 1, size(a)
    inter(j) = any(a(j) == b)
END DO
```

If you want to find the largest, say, n values, you can use something like this:

```
function largest(vars, n)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: vars
    real, dimension(n) :: largest
    integer :: i
    logical, dimension(size(vars)) :: m
    integer :: mloc

    m = .TRUE.

    do i = 1, n
       mloc = maxloc(vars, DIM=1, MASK=m)
       m(mloc) = .FALSE.
       largest(i) = vars(mloc)
    end do
    return
end function largest
```

Basically it uses a mask that is all true, then every time it reverts the mask for the highest to false to not get that value again in the next iteration.

Of course, this is of order (n*size(var)), so if n is large, it might be quicker to do a bubble sort until you have the n largest values accumulated at the end, and then pick them up.

Comment: Ah yes, this line is what I was looking for `m(mloc) = .FALSE.`. What I was currently using was pretty much the same as what you have but with `vars(mloc) = 0.` instead (all my values are positive). Your method allows me to keep it succinct without having to worry about altering `vars`.